# Downvoting multiple bad posts without serial voting reversal script

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

What happens when I've identified a lot of bad posts from [a particular user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5254505/gerrit-van-weele).  Based on their current merit, each probably deserve downvotes for not showing any research effort, being unclear, and not generally useful. Also, a lot of them are duplicates of one another, in an attempt to throw out as many ropes as possible, hoping someone will grab onto one of them.

I've cast close votes on all of them, but believe it's appropriate to downvote as well.  However, I'm worried that if I downvote all 4 questions, the serial voting reversal will remove them.  But they all seem to warrant downvotes.

This is all after trying to [briefly explain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32774140/1366033) some of the appropriate posting etiquette, but without much effort to improve existing answers.

Comment: This is pretty unanswerable. Even though your intentions are good, the answer is also the answer to "How do I avoid the serial voting detection script" which the devs obviously don't want us to know.

Comment: That's pretty much the definition of serial voting.  Even if all the posts warrant downvotes, you really shouldn't be focusing on the posts of a single user.  That's a targeted set of votes against a single person.  If there's something abnormally bad going on, raise a moderator flag instead and let them deal with it.

Comment: @ryanyuyu, it absolutely is serial voting, but I believe not a horrendous use of it.  @ Bradley, I'm not trying so much to circumvent serial down voting, but identify a use case where it's occasionally appropriate.  I think the key position here is that all of the posts, **on their own merit** deserve attention.

Comment: Take **your time** to judge them one by one. Not more than 2-3 in a single day. I've been victim of sich strategy used abusively, and the serial downvoting reversal script didn't run.

Comment: I've found the script to be tolerant if I run into the user's posts while scanning for activity on a tag. For instance, I'll sometimes see new users use the spray and pray approach to answering: lots of low quality answers posted in quick succession. I've usually not had trouble downvoting the posts of such users.

Comment: Now I may be totally wrong here, but I was under the impression (from a comment somewhere on a meta post) that HOW you find these posts might be relevant as well. If you organically find, through looking up a tag's new questions, questions by the same guy, ok. If you go through a guy's profile and just read every question, then proceed to downvote, maybe not

Comment: "it's easy to find... user profiles - full of terrible stuff. But if you're going to review them, do it right: up-vote the good stuff, down-vote the bad stuff, edit the stuff that should be edited, leave comments where you can do some good that way... If you can't do that, then you're not really giving these posts a fair shake and you shouldn't be reviewing them at all..." ([How should I balance serial downvoting with the discovery that a poster has a lot of downvotable posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210257/165773))